# Create query that lists work items that was lifted into the current iteration after it started

Tags: azure-devops

I want to write a query to get those work items that were added half heartedly into the current iteration after we had the sprint planning in the start of the current sprint.

Is that possible?

I can check if Iteration Path equals @CurrentIteration, and if Created Date is greater than @StartOfDay, but then my clues are exhausted.

There is no @StartOfIteration or Moved To Iteration Date. Is there something else I can use?

Comment: Hi @Anders Lindén, you could report this as a feature suggestion by [suggest feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). I have updated my answer below, if it helps just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the query below to get the work items that created before your current sprint start. You could use use +/- n to define the specific days that your current sprint start. Please refer to [Query by date or current iteration in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops) for more information.

[image]

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#create-child-nodes-modify-work-items-under-an-area-or-iteration-path), area path permissions let you grant or restrict access to edit or modify work items, test cases, or test plans assigned to those areas. You can restrict access to users or groups. You can also set permissions for who can add or modify areas or iterations for the project.

Thus, you can only restrict access to edit or modify work items by setting area path permission. You could refer to [Query sprint scope changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/scrum-overview?view=azure-devops#query-sprint-scope-changes) about the query to List work items added after the start of the sprint or List work items moved out of the sprint.

Update: If you want this feature, you could report this as a feature suggestion by [suggest feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). Such as Restrict access to edit or modify work items in current sprint.

Comment: Then I need to alter the query every day. Also, old work items can be moved into the current sprint.

Comment: Yes, there is no such built-in feature to restrict access to edit or modify work items in current sprint. I updated the answer, please refer to related document.